# Object mapping for Project Voldemort

Tags: java, orm, voldemort

I've been trying to find a Object mapping library for `Project Voldemort`; however I can't seem to find one.

- Are there any Object mapping library/framework for Voldemort written in Java
- Either mature project or just starting out